# Blocky fire in rendered view

Tags: volumetrics, fire

In the render view my fire is kinda "blocky". No matter it is in Eevee or Cycles. When I change Emission to 0 and Blackbody Intensity to 1, is better, but this is not the result I want to achieve. Any ideas?

I also attach link to the file: [blocky_fire.blend](https://we.tl/t-Zq1OC6tsEe)
[image: Fire problem]

Comment: Your blend file link is expired and doesn't work. Have you tried the answer of Julius? He mentioned you just need to change the *Color* node to *Multiply*

Answer (score 1):

Setting the *Mix RGB* node to <kbd>***Multiply***</kbd> will fix your problem.

Hope this helps!